# VB6.0 Adding a record to a Database (Listview)

Tags: database, listview, vb6, transactions

I got an error whenever i clicked this command. Im trying to put the transaction history on the fields of TransactionNo and Earnings and the other fields are just for inventory.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim earnings As Double
earnings = txtCash - txtChange
ConnectDB
rs.Open "Select TransactionNo, Earnings from Table2", db, 3, 3
rs.AddNew
    rs(0) = txtNumber 'rs(1) is an auto number
     rs(2) = txtProduct 'Here i got an error, it says Item cannot be found in the 'collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal
      rs(3) = txtStockLeft
       rs(4) = txtPricePiece
        rs(5) = txtExpiry
          rs(6) = earnings
rs.Update
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set rs = Nothing
LoadData1
ListView2.ListItems.Clear
LoadData
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change code `rs(2) = txtProduct` to `rs(1) = txtProduct`

You will not get error on that line when you change code according to i said.

But you will get error on line below

```
rs(3) = txtStockLeft
rs(4) = txtPricePiece
rs(5) = txtExpiry
```

This is because your select query is only returning 2 columns `Select TransactionNo, Earnings from Table2`. You need to include other relevant columns.

Comment: It helped i select all the columns 
ConnectDB
    rs.Open "Table2", db, 3, 3

And i just hide the other data using 0 width
With ListView2.ColumnHeaders
.Add , , "ID", 10
.Add , , "Number", 1000
.Add , , "ProductName", 0
.Add , , "Stock", 0
.Add , , "PricePiece", 0
.Add , , "Expiry", 0
.Add , , "Earnings", 1200